# Regular expression in ruby to find value of xml node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, regex, parsing

I want to make a regular express to parse out the value (29.0) from this node:

```
"<currentPrice currencyId="USD">29.0</currentPrice>"
```

in an xml document. And I would like the value (price) of each and every instance of that node. There is no limit or minimum to what price could be.

Comment: this is not what regexes were designed for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Nokogiri::XML(myXml).xpath('//currentPrice/text()').map(&:to_s)`

Using a regexp to parse XML makes certain infant deities cry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to answer this question, by using Ruby's standard Library [`REXML`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/index.html)

```
require 'rexml/document'

@doc = REXML::Document.new('<currentPrice currencyId="USD">29.0</currentPrice>')
@doc.get_elements("//currentPrice")[0].text # => "29.0"
```